# Controlling for a Variable, do not know if it is a moderating variable

Tags: interaction, interpretation, partial-correlation

I conducted a Spearman's correlation to determine if there was a relationship between emotional clarity and cognitive empathy. I found that they were positively associated, but the relationship was not significant.

I then controlled for depression in a partial correlation, since I expected that less clarity = depression = impaired cognitive empathy, and that depression would be a confounding variable. Instead, emotional clarity was negatively correlated with depression, and depression was positively correlated with cognitive empathy (instead of negatively correlated as expected) and so there was no confounding effect. However, the partial correlation showed that by adjusting for depression, the clarity-cognitive empathy relationship became significant. I don't know how to interpret this result, because I only expected depression to strengthen, rather than weaken, the clarity- cognitive empathy relationship. Removing depression strengthened the relationship.

I can't conduct any more analyses as I have to submit my dissertation soon, so it's really about interpreting my results as best I can.

Could it be a moderating variable? So, at moderate levels of depression the clarity-cognitive empathy relationship is weak, but at high levels of depression, the relationship is stronger?

Any help is much appreciated!